# Ошибка переопределения массива в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-3.7

При написании кода, столкнулся с проблемой, заключающейся в неожиданных результатах, полученных после переопределения массива на основе его глубокой копии.

Приведу пример:

```py
import copy

mas = [['blue'] * 3] * 3
mas[0] = ['red'] * 3

copy_mas = copy.deepcopy(mas)

mas[0][2] = copy_mas[0][0]
mas[2][2] = copy_mas[0][2]
```

После исполнения массив `mas` выглядит так:

```py
mas = [['red', 'red', 'red'], ['blue', 'blue', 'red'], ['blue', 'blue', 'red']]
```

Значение `mas[1][2]` изменилось, однако, в коде я его не изменял.

Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь сможет объяснить, почему это происходит и предложить альтернативное решение, в котором можно изменять массив на основе его копии без подобных казусов.

Comment: Ну так вы не копию меняли. `mas[2]` и `mas[1]` это **один и тот же** массив, а массив `mas[2]` вы всё-таки меняли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании массива, Вы множите не данные, а ссылки на один и тот же объект массива.

Вот проблемная строка:

```py
mas = [['blue'] * 3] * 3
```

После исполнения этой инструкции, массив `mas` будет содержать 3 ссылки на один и тот же объект массива.
Докажем это, воспользовавшись оператором `is`:

```
print(mas[0] is mas[1] is mas[2])  # True
```

Именно поэтому инструкция `mas[2][2] = copy_mas[0][2]` также затронет элемент `mas[1]`

---

Для того чтобы избежать копирования ссылок, можно воспользоваться генератором списков:

```
mas = [['blue'] * 3 for i in range(3)]
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ

Comment: @Python_beginner Я обновил ответ, добавив информацию о том, как можно этого избежать. Если ответ Вам помог, то Вы можете пометить его как верный.

Answer (score 0):

```
mas = [['blue'] * 3] * 3
# mas состоит из: [[объект blue1], [объект blue1], [объект blue1]]
mas[0] = ['red'] * 3
# mas состоит из: [[объект red1], [объект blue1], [объект blue1]]
copy_mas = copy.deepcopy(mas)
mas[0][2] = copy_mas[0][0]
# mas = [[объект red1 изменен], [объект blue1], [объект blue1]]
mas[2][2] = copy_mas[0][2]
# mas = [[объект red1], [объект blue1 изменен], [объект blue1 изменен]]
```